# How to add line break in PDFbox JAVA

Tags: java, pdfbox, line-breaks

im generating a PDF file with some comments, cells, tables... Im working with PDFbox in JAVA

I would like to add a line break to my string which its called "escComments" and it contain an array of Comments.

I've tried "\n", "\r", "System.getProperty(“line.separator”)" and nothing works.

This is my code:

```
if (action.getCloseComment() != null) {

String escComments = action.getCloseComment();
escComments = escapeChars(escComments);
            
            
row.put( "COMENTARIOS", escComments);
}
```

I would like to add a line break for each comment comming from getCloseComment()

Comment: The code you show does not directly interact with PDFBox. Please show your _relevant_ code.

Answer (score 1):

```
try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page))
{
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    contents.beginText();
    contents.setFont(font, 12);
    contents.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    contents.showText(line1);
    contents.newLineAtOffset(0, -50);
    contents.showText(line2);
    contents.newLineAtOffset(0, -50);
    contents.showText(line3);
    contents.endText();
}
```

Comment: That's not the point, I appreciate the answer but im asking about add line break for my string, i mean I have a string with the next structure (date + comment) and i want to add a line break before the next date

Comment: You need to split the string yourself. PDFBox won't interpret the line break.

Comment: I splited the string in 2 differents ways, 1 is using the classic .split() and 2 is using replaceAll() (replacing for example a "." and adding the line break) and nothing works... its... disgusting...

Comment: split is the thing you need. You need to write code so that each string gets written after calling `newLineAtOffset`. Note that the first X Y values are relative to 0,0 with is the bottom left (thus 100,700 is near the top of the page), after that only the Y value changes. If it doesn't work, please edit the question to include the code that you used.

Answer (score 0):

you can try 'moveTextPositionByAmount' to split string and move the text position to next line.

Comment: can you give a example? i've never used that function